# GitHub facing while pushing it to remote

Tags: git, github

I created the repository in GitHub and I have not created any branch I edited the same master branch without creating a new branch.

Any one please guide me how to push the edited master to remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First* you need to commit any changes you have made to the `master` branch:

```
git commit -m Made changes to the master branch
```

*Next* you can push `master` out to the remote via:

```
git push origin master
```

To see if you have any changes in your local `master` branch you can type `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've committed your changes locally, the syntax is `git push <remotename> <branchname>`, so you could simply use `git push origin master`.

For additional details, you could check out [github's help](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can switch to a different branch, changes will remain on that branch:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

Then, you can [simply](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

<sup>You can use `push` without creating a branch, directly from your master branch</sup>